# Скрытие активити андроид

Tags: java, android, activity

Столкнулся с проблемой в разработке андроид. Нужно СКРЫТЬ приложение.
Известно, что finish() - закрывает приложение, а что его скрывает?(Аналог кнопки "домой")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать сворачиванием приложения:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Свернутое приложение будет в разделе недавних приложений.